# Else Statement Does Not Stop Looping NodeJS

Tags: node.js, for-loop, if-statement

I have been working on this code to read through a PDF file and grab the keywords of company names and display them. It all works fine except for one part where the else if statement outputs one line (which is what I want) but the else statement that comes last, which is supposed to output "Not Found" loops 20 times where I only want it to display the output only once instead of 20 times.

I have tried numerous ways by going through the internet to change my code, most recommended that forEach is not a proper way to do things and that I should use for instead but when I do, I just can't seem to get it right.

```
l.forEach(function(element) {

    var j = element['fullTextAnnotation']['text'];   
    var sd = 'SDN. BHD.';
    var bd = 'BHD.';
    var et = 'Enterprise'; 
    var inc = 'Incorporated'; 

    var regtoken = new natural.RegexpTokenizer({pattern:/\n/});
    var f = regtoken.tokenize(jsondata);   

for(o = 0 ; o < f.length; o++){
    var arrayline1 = natural.LevenshteinDistance(sd,f[o],{search:true});
    var arrayline2 = natural.LevenshteinDistance(bd,f[o],{search:true});
    var arrayline3 = natural.LevenshteinDistance(et,f[o],{search:true});
    var arrayline4 = natural.LevenshteinDistance(inc,f[o],{search:true});
    var arrayline5 = natural.LevenshteinDistance(nf,f[o],{search:false});

    var onedata1 = arrayline1['substring'];
    var onedata2 = arrayline2['substring'];
    var onedata3 = arrayline3['substring'];
    var onedata4 = arrayline4['substring'];
    var onedata5 = arrayline5['substring'];

    if (onedata1 === sd)
    {
        tokends = f[o];            
        break;
    } else if(onedata3 === et)

    {
        tokends = f[o];
        break;

    } else if(onedata2 === bd) 

    {
        tokends = f[o];
        console.log(tokends);
        break;

    } else if(onedata4 === inc)

    {
        tokends = f[o];
        console.log(tokends);
        break;

    } else{

       console.log("Not Found");
       return false;    
    }  

}

});
```

I wish to get only one "Not Found" output for the else statement rather than it looping it for 20 times over. Hopefully I could get some insight to this problem. Thank you.

Comment: You have 2 for loops nested, I think your issue is with the main `forEach` loop, that is not going to break in any way. If you want to work on a sublist you should use a `filter` before the `forEach`.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any sort of reference that I can look through because I'm not entirely sure on how to do it.

Comment: The first step is to write the code with the guard conditions in advance, I mean the check that identifies your case as invalid or "Not Fount". That conditions will do the filter. Here you have a good documentation about arrays methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: I tried following it, now it's giving me an error about s.split being undefined (which I've gotten before by trying to remove the for loop out). The documentation teaches about arrays but doesn't define how excessive looping could be overcome..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually using the `.forEach` Array's method which actually take a function in parameter.

The keywork `return` breaks actually the loop of the current function executed.

For example :

```
const data = ['Toto', 'Tata', 'Titi'];

data.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log(element);
    if (element === 'Tata') {
        return false;
    }
});

// Will print everything :
// Print Toto
// Print Tata 
// Print Titi

for (let element of data) {
    console.log(element);
    if (element === 'Tata') {
        return false;
    }
}
// Will print :
// Print Toto
// Print Tata
```

Comment: The problem is when I try to remove the for function and place it outside of forEach, the declared variables are no longer accessible and I end up with undefined errors. I tried to overcome this problem but changing forEach to for statement but then I get new problems somethings such as split is undefined

Comment: Update, got it to work thanks to the let element constructor. Thank you :)